# I'm trying to generate date from week number using moment JS

Tags: momentjs

As per the documentation, the following code should work:

```js
moment(moment('2020043').format("YYYYwwe")).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

I'm trying to get 3rd day of 4th week of 2020

[jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/5ptndmgu/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and use `YYYYWWE` as parsing tokens (case sensitive), where `YYYY` is the 4 digit year `WW` is ISO week of year and `E` is ISO day of week.

Example:

```js
console.log(moment('2020043', "YYYYWWE").format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: quick question, can you please guide me to api doc page, where they have documented this particular constructor? somehow i am not able to spot it.

Comment: I've already put the link of [String + Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) in my answer,in general you can have a look at the [Parse](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) section and the [Parsing Guide](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/)